# I drive from Channel Tunnel Calais to Kempten in Germany on 18.06.19 what would be the quickest route

Tags: transit

I would like to use as much unlimited autobahn as possible as I am familiar with driving on German autobahn and time is a factor.

Comment: to make this an answerable question, ask pieces of it. You presumably have a possible route in mind. Then you aren't just using that route. Why? Are you concerned about delays on part of it? Specifically? Do you want to know which of two specific roads will be quicker? Ask a crisper question and you can get an answer. "Tell me what to do" -- can't be answered.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to optimize the time, your best shot is to follow the real time advice from Google Maps (or equivalent).

Currently the fastest route stays in France most of the time and only crosses into Germany at Baden Baden. If you want more driving in Germany you can go through Belgium and cross around Bitburg. But that's 20 minutes more of "normal" driving time and it's unlikely that you could make this up by going "fast".

Keep in mind: while some Autobahns in Germany have no speed limits, the actual speed you can go safely is often fairly limited by construction, traffic, road conditions, weather, and varies greatly during the day and from one day to another. So the occasions, where you can actually make some time will be quite limited and its also not really predictable. That's the value of real time navigation that's based on current traffic and road conditions.